# Can't send a link to my own wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am developing a multi protocol client (currently Twitter, Facebook and Google Reader) for Windows using C# and wanted to extend its functions to send links to Facebook (currently I "only" have text status messages, comments and likes).

So I wrote this quite small method here:

```
public void PostLink(string text, string url)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
        {
            PostTextStatus(text);
            return;
        }

        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters.message = text;
        parameters.link = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url);

        dynamic result = facebookClient.Post("me/links", parameters);
        UpdateNewsFeed();
    }
```

But I get the following error message back from Facebook: "(OAuthException) (#1500) The url you supplied is invalid"

But at least as I read the API docs this should be the right url and I tried it also with my user ID instead of "me" and without the UrlEncode - no luck so far.

Any help appreciated :)

(Using latest stable version für Facebook C# SDK)

The used client is initiated by

```
 facebookClient = new FacebookClient(AccessToken);

            dynamic result = (IDictionary<string, object>)facebookClient.Get("me");

            if (result != null)
            {
                LoginSuccessfull = true;
            }
  }
```

and the AccesToken and its permissions were retrieved using

```
  IDictionary<string, object> loginParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
                                                          {
                                                              { "response_type", "token" },
                                                              { "appId", appId},
                                                              { "secret", appSecret }

                                                          };

        Uri redirectUri = new Uri("http://www.li-ghun.de/Nymphicus/");
        loginUri = FacebookOAuthClient.GetLoginUrl(appId, null, _extendedPermissions, loginParameters);
```

with I think quite more than enough permissons:

```
 private string[] _extendedPermissions = new[] { 
         "user_activities",
         "user_birthday",
         "user_checkins",
         "user_education_history",
         "user_events",
         "user_games_activity",      
         "user_groups",
         "user_hometown",
         "user_interests",
         "user_likes",
         "user_location",
         "user_notes",
         "user_online_presence",
         "user_photo_video_tags",
         "user_photos",
         "user_questions",
         "user_relationship_details",
         "user_relationships",
         "user_religion_politics",
         "user_status",
         "user_subscriptions",
         "user_videos",
         "user_website",
         "user_work_history",


         "friends_about_me",
         "friends_activities",
         "friends_birthday",
         "friends_checkins",
         "friends_education_history",
         "friends_events",
         "friends_games_activity",
         "friends_groups",
         "friends_hometown",
         "friends_interests",
         "friends_likes",
         "friends_location",
         "friends_notes",
         "friends_online_presence",
         "friends_photo_video_tags",
         "friends_photos",
         "friends_questions",
         "friends_relationship_details",
         "friends_relationships",
         "friends_religion_politics",
         "friends_status",
         "friends_subscriptions",
         "friends_videos",
         "friends_website",
         "friends_work_history",

        "create_event",
        "create_note",
        "email",
        "export_stream",
        "manage_friendlists",
        "manage_notifications",
        "manage_pages",
        "offline_access",
        "photo_upload",
        "publish_actions",
        "publish_checkins",
        "publish_stream",
        "read_friendlists",
        "read_insights",
        "read_mailbox",
        "read_requests",
        "read_stream",
        "rsvp_event",
        "share_item",
        "status_update",
        "video_upload",
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem has been all the time at myself being stupid - I accidently exchanged the parameters when calling my method so the text of the entry was in the link property and vica versa.

Stupid me :(

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue lies in the URL being posted as the link.  Be sure that URL is visible to the linter (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint).

Another thing is to try playing with the Graph API Explorer tool and see if you can use it to post a link.  If so, then try changing the application drop down to the app you're having issues with and try posting the link again.

Comment: Where did my own answer disappear? Sorry, the problem was me being so stupid to exchange the parameters on call of my method  :(

Comment: Did you learn about the parameter issue from using the explorer tool?

Comment: Excellent! Glad to hear you found the issue.  :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case i was posting "http://localhost:3000" and facebook reject it. I tried with "www.google.com" and it works

Answer (score 0):

The error I was getting was, even though the URL itself was valid, the og:image was being set to `//example.com/example.jpg` and missing `http:` or `https:`. I blame Facebook for this one, for not accepting a valid URL that any browser will accept, but the Debugger definitely helped identify this and solved the issue.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint